# Can I add another network interface to my EC2 instance at launch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My machine image requires 2 network interfaces. I want to avoid having to manually do that after the instance is brought up. Is there a way to add the 2nd network interface during Launch? either in the AWS GUI or scripted way, I am open to both.

I know how to add the second interface to an instance after it has been created. I would like to minimize the amount of work I have to do after the fact. I want to streamline this part of the process to make it easier for the users to consume this image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add ENIs to an EC2 during configuration via the Console. To do this, start launching an instance and go to **Network Settings > Advanced Network Configuration > Add Network Interface**.

Just know the number of ENIs you can add is dependent on your instance type. This info can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#AvailableIpPerENI

If you want this automated, use Infrastructure as Code or the create a script that uses the AWS CLI

Comment: At the Launch screen, I do not see Advanced Network Configuration...

Comment: @MayurRaol Make sure you have a subnet selected. Then you should see that option.

Comment: Jake, you da man! ... selecting the subnet was the key... Thank you so much 